# D language cast operator overload problem

Tags: operator-overloading, immutability, d

I'm playing with D2 at the moment, I would like to write some simple program but i'm stuck with operator cast overload...I have a Vector class that can be cast to Normal :

```
class Vector {
    public float x,y,z; 
    this(in float x, in float y, in float z){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    //..............

    Normal opCast(T)() if (is(T == Normal)){
        return new Normal(this.x,this.y,this.z);
    }
}
```

If i write something like

```
immutable Vector v = cast(immutable(Vector))new Vector(0F, 0F, 0F);
```

the compiler complains that : 
"template instance opCast!(immutable(Vector)) does not match template declaration opCast(T) if (is(T == Normal))"

If I omit the cast:

```
immutable Vector v = new Vector(0F,0F,0F);
```

the message changes, but the program does not compile: 
"cannot implicitly convert expression (new Vector(0F,0F,0F)) of type Vector to immutable(Vector)"

If I omit the cast operator overload in the Vector class all compile just fine.

Put in a different way...How can I assign or cast an instance to an immutable 'var'?

Comment: I think you should be able to do 'auto v = new immutable(Vector)(0f,0f,0f);'

Comment: "class Vector" is a supremely bad idea. I assure you, you do not want to force a memory allocation for every vector operation you perform. Use "struct Vector" instead. _Please_.

Answer (score 1):

you should not overload `opCast` normally.

commonly methods named *toTypename* are used for object that knows how to convert itself to another.

```
Normal toNormal () { return new Normal (x, y, z); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions:

- A pretty solution is what Trass3r already mentioned in his comment: Treat `immmutable(Vector)` as its own data type (it is), and call its constructor.
- A somewhat uglier solution is to use `assumeUnique()` on the object you want to cast. I think you might need to import a library (`std.exception`, if I'm not wrong).